# hide out of stock products woocommerce but not the reviews

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to remove or hide products from the woo-commerce shop page but I want to keep the reviews on that products. is there any way to do that?

Comment: Check this screenshot - https://barn2.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/hide-woocommerce-products-1-820x423.jpg also this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtgcP.png if you want all products automatically hidden

Comment: yes, I know these ways. but they also hide products. but reviews on products to visible.

Comment: You want them visible where ? They are reviews **of the product**.

Comment: yes, I have products on site. people left reviews and now the product is out of stock. and I want to remove or hide the product but not the reviews. I have a widget in the footer which shows recent reviews.